# sql query to get conflicts on time like an alarm

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m trying to create an sql query to get a list of possible conflicts on my table but so far my sql doesn’t work.
The idea is to have like an alarm function

If `date_start = date_end` that means one shot

Example: `date_start = 2018-11-07 10:37:00` and `date_end = 2018-11-07 10:37:00`

If `date_start not null` and `date _end = null` , one of the days column should be different from `0`

Example:  `date_start = 2018-11-07 10:37:00 and date_end = NULL and Monday = 2` 
.
That means starting the `start_date` every Monday I’m gonna get the row at that time

My problem now is that I’m trying to get a list of conflicts if I have 2 rows that can be at the same time and date . Here is an example of my database:

[image: sampledb]

I created an sql query above but It’s not working well, any one can help ?

```
SELECT
        id
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        date_start IN(
        SELECT
            date_start
        FROM
            my_table
        WHERE
            date_start = date_end 
        GROUP BY
            date_start
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    )
    UNION
    SELECT
        id
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%H:%i:%s') IN(
        SELECT
            DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%H:%i:%s')
        FROM
            my_table
        WHERE
            date_end IS NULL AND(
                monday = 2 OR tuesday = 3 OR wednesday = 4 OR thursday = 5 OR friday = 6 OR saturday = 7 OR sunday = 1
            )
        GROUP BY
            DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%H:%i:%s')
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    )
    UNION
    SELECT
        id
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%H:%i:%s') IN(

        SELECT
            CASE WHEN
                        (DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 2 AND (select monday from my_table where monday = 2) IS NOT NULL)
                     OR (DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 3 AND (select tuesday from my_table where tuesday = 3) IS NOT NULL)
                     OR (DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 4 AND (select wednesday from my_table where wednesday = 4) IS NOT NULL)
                     OR (DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 5 AND (select thursday from my_table where thursday = 5) IS NOT NULL)
                     OR (DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 6 AND (select friday from my_table where friday = 6) IS NOT NULL)
                     OR (DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 7 AND (select saturday from my_table where saturday = 7) IS NOT NULL)
                     OR (DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 1 AND (select sunday from my_table where sunday = 1) IS NOT NULL)
                 THEN DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%H:%i:%s')
                 ELSE NULL
                 END
        FROM
            my_table
        WHERE
            (DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 2
                                   OR DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 3
                                   OR DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 4
                                   OR DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 5
                                   OR DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 6
                                   OR DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 7
                                   OR DAYOFWEEK(date_start) = 1
            )
        GROUP BY
            DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%H:%i:%s')
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

Comment: What's the database? And please post the table structure.

Comment: date_start and date_end are timestamp , monday column and the other days columns are int

Comment: @summoner I think The Impaler was asking which SQL database are you running (Eg. MS-SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle)

Comment: ah sorry,  it's mySQL

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve...  What's the purpose of this table?  What is the data you are getting back with the code you supplied and what why isn't it right?  If you want help with a problem like this, please go through the work to put a test case on a site like [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: As I explained , it’s an alarm app that saves the date and the time to start 
I wanna have an sql query that return the rows that have same time to start in the same day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
SELECT date_start FROM alarms 
WHERE date_end IS NULL AND 
monday + tuesday + wednesday + thursday + friday + saturday + sunday > 0 
GROUP BY TIME(date_start) 
HAVING COUNT(monday)>0 OR COUNT(tuesday)>0 OR COUNT(wednesday)>0 OR 
COUNT(thursday)>0 OR COUNT(friday)>0 OR COUNT(saturday)>0 OR COUNT(sunday)>0
```

### UPDATE

If you want to catch conflicts between one-shot events and weekly events you can use a query like this

```
SELECT a1.date_start AS oneshow,a2.date_start AS weekly,DAYOFWEEK(a1.date_start) as dow 
FROM alarms AS a1
LEFT JOIN alarms AS a2 ON
  a1.date_start >= a2.date_start AND a2.date_end IS NULL
    AND TIME(a1.date_start) = TIME(a2.date_start)
    AND DAYOFWEEK(a1.date_start) IN (a2.monday, a2.tuesday, a2.wednesday, a2.thursday, a2.friday, a2.saturday, a2.sunday)
WHERE a1.date_end IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it's not working . I still have many conflicts when I used your query

Comment: The purpose of the query is to catch and show ONLY the conflicts - and it shows each conflicting TIME only ONCE. When you have the time - you should make another query to fetch all rows which contain that time (and are not one-time events). If you need the opposite - i.e. not the list of existing conflicts but a way to PREVENT conflicts - then you have to switch the database to PostgreSQL, it allows using exclusion constraints so that you can not insert a time interval which overlaps with any of the existing time intervals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First I don’t want prevent the conflicts . I want to allow the user to add rows on the same date and same time and then I will display a list of warnings based on the conflicts. Second, I succeeded to get the conflicts on my query for the one shots (date_ start = date_end) and the weekly repeat(date_end is null and one of the days column is different from 0). My problem now is the conflicts between one shot and weekly repeat. ex: repeat every monday and one shot is on monday both at the same time.On the database I shared you can find the case on the last 2 rows.